# How can I fadeIn/fadeOut of text using jQuery (or CSS)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm building a random quote generator and would like to use the fadeIn/fadeOut function when switching between quotes when prompted by a button click. However I'm not sure how to target the text in jQuery, since I am printing the array directly from Javascript like this:

```
$('.show-quote').text(randomQuote);
```

Here is the project so far:

http://codepen.io/biancalelei/pen/vLeJVd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GoMGQL

```
$('.show-quote').fadeOut(300, function(){
   $(this).text(randomQuote).fadeIn(300)
});
```

First, it will fade out in 300ms. When it is done the attached function will be executed. It changes the text and then fades it back in.

If you don't want the background to fade out as well, you can put the text in extra `<div>`: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OMxEvK

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to do, Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$('.show-quote').fadeIn()` and `$('.show-quote').fadeOut()`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, first fadeOut 300ms and then fadeIn 300ms after that text print

```
$('.show-quote').fadeOut(300).fadeIn(300).text(randomQuote);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can chain jQuery functions to achieve the functionality. Something like this:

```
$('.show-quote').hide().html(randomQuote).fadeIn(1000);
```

CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wMrXyv